# How to Create Dynamic-Sized Paged Horizontal UIScrollView Using AutoLayout in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, storyboard, autolayout

I Want to create a UIScrollView In Storyboard Using AutoLayout.

- Horizontal Paged Scrolling Enabled,
- Dynamic Page Size Adaptability (that is, page size should adapt for iPhone 4s thru iPhone 6 Plus screen size)

I'd be thankful if someone would give me a direction as to how I Should proceed to achieve this.

I have searched around the web for this but haven't found anything as clear and as accurate to what I want to achieve.

Comment: Have you checked out UIPageViewController?https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/index.html

Comment: @NewEngland No. I haven't checked it yet (Thanks for telling though, I'll surely check it out once through with this). But I don't think its gonna be of any help as I want to show UIViews as pages and not UIViewControllers.

Comment: you can also check this link http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/05/uiscrollview-autolayout-ios/

Comment: So, that's essentially one really wide view with subviews for each page embedded in a scrollView? I made a template project you can adapt: http://github.com/annabd351/AutolayoutTemplate

Comment: @VinodJadhav I have been through this link. My exact issue is resizing the pages of UIScrollView in accordance with device screen width (i'm creating horizontal content scroll view)

Comment: @AnnaDickinson Thanks for the link. I Checked it out. Helped me correct another problem of another project (thanks for that!), but not this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it myself.
Here is the link to my demo of what I wanted to achieve.
Hope this helps others too.
https://github.com/ArshAulakh59/ScrollAutoLayoutTest

Apologies for the delay guys but now I have added the steps to achieve this via video on the github page.

Comment: @ArchAulakh I Checked your Answer. It works exactly, how I want, But I cannot find any description there, how you achieved this. Could you please explain how you set the Constraints for ScrollView. In my case I found them not working.

Comment: @Jeev I'm glad it helped. Sure give me some time to add a description of how I accomplished it on the github page itself.

Comment: Can you please specify the steps to do it